Python - isoTP lib cannot sending consecutive frame after get flow control frame
as you see on the title
I'm using python 3.13.1 with can-isotp2.0.6 and python-can 4.5.0 and USB-CAN Robotell for hardware
my scrip
def send_msg(data)
    channel = find_Robotell_port()
    paramsdata = load_setup ("setup.json")
    bus = can.interface.Bus(interface='robotell', channel=channel, bitrate=500000)
    data_byte = bytes([int(x,16) for x in data])
    addr = isotp.Address(isotp.AddressingMode.Normal_11bits, rxid=0x62C, txid=0x6AC)
    params = paramsdata["Parameters"]
    stack = isotp.CanStack(bus, address=addr, error_handler=my_error_handler, params=params)
 
    try:
        stack.start()
        stack.send(data = data_byte, send_timeout= 5)
    except isotp.BlockingSendFailure:  
        Print('failure to send')
    finally:
        stack.stop()
        bus.shutdown()

and here is params:
"Parameters": {
        "stmin" : 10,
        "blocksize" : 0,
        "tx_data_length" : 8,
        "tx_data_min_length" : 8,
        "override_receiver_stmin" :1000,
        "rx_flowcontrol_timeout" : 10000,
        "rx_consecutive_frame_timeout" : 1000,
        "tx_padding": 255,
        "wftmax" : 0,
        "max_frame_size" : 4095,
        "can_fd" : false,
        "bitrate_switch" : false,
        "default_target_address_type": 0,
        "rate_limit_enable" : false,
        "rate_limit_max_bitrate"  : 10000000,
        "rate_limit_window_size" : 0.2,
        "listen_mode" : false,
        "blocking_send" :true,
        "logger_name" : "CAN_TP"

it working fine with payload under 8byte (single frame) but have problem when payload over 8byte: after sending the first frame and recv the flow control. tester doesn't send any consecutive frame and raise exception: BlockingSendFailure
For example:
i tried with data: input = ['0x67','0x03','0xec', '0x45', '0xf2', '0x63', '0xd0', '0xd8', '0xae', '0x9d', '0x2d', '0xb3', '0x23', '0x0', '0x30', '0x73', '0xc0', '0x89','0x73', '0xc0', '0x89'] 
send : 10 15 67 03 EC 45 F2 63 (first frame)
recv : 30 08 14 00 00 00 00 00 (flow control)
send : nothing and raise exception

so is there any idea for me to fix this problem
Thanks
fix the problem, maybe wrong setup for isotp

I see nothing wrong with your code. Have you tried py-uds package? It is also compatible with python-can. Here is some example.

Thanks Maciek for your advise, i have read your package, it have great idea and i cant wait to use this for other project with LIN or other bus.
About my problem, i found the issue come from my setup of override_receiver_stmin parameter, i changed it to 0 and it work well with >8byte payload now
